# Integrating Leaflet and Bootstrap: help refactoring my css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, refactoring, leaflet

I'm trying to use Bootstrap to structure a page containing a leaflet map.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

I've been unable to do it with bootstrap.

I wrote some ugly css which barely works:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container-fluid fill">
  <div class="row-fluid fill">

    <div class="span9 fill-height">
        <div  id="map"></div>
      </div>
       <div class="span3">
      <div id="filters">

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#map
{
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

.fill
{  padding-left: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.fill-height
{  padding-left: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

body
{
    padding-top: 40px; /*for navbar*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox, other Gecko */
     box-sizing: border-box; /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

I had to remove the padding to prevent overflow, so now my form has no padding.

**My question:**

How do I obtain that structure with the bootstrap classes? How can I keep the padding but only for the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still a lot of css, needed, but padding problems solved:

```
    #map
{
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}



html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

.fill
{  padding: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.fill-height
{  padding: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

body
{
    padding-top: 40px; /*for navbar*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="container-fluid fill">
  <div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span9 fill-height" >
        <div  id="map"></div>
      </div>
       <div class="span3">
      <div id="filters">

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

& css should be something like this.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
html, body, #map, .row-fluid{
    height: 100%;
}
#map {
    width: 100%;
}

.fill-height
{  padding-left: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Comment: what problem you are having ?

Comment: the row is only hundred px deep.